# Unable to insert Number into a text box

Tags: c#, oracle, type-conversion, datareader

I have a web application which uses Oracle as it's DB. I have a query which returns number to the front end which I need to insert into a text box.

When the number returned is a whole number, the textbox gets populated but when the number returned is a decimal, it throws an error "Specified cast is not valid."

Here is the code.

```
string isbn=Request.QueryString["code"];
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

con.Open();

string sql = "SELECT distinct B.TITLE,B.BOOK_CATEGORY,B.ISBN,A.AUTHOR_NAME,P.PUBLICATION_HOUSE_NAME,B.YEAR_OF_PUBLICATION,(SELECT AVG(AVERAGE_RATING) FROM RATING_TABLE GROUP BY ISBN HAVING ISBN = '" + isbn + "') AS AVERAGE from BOOK_TABLE B JOIN AUTHOR_TABLE A ON B.AUTHOR_ID = A.AUTHOR_ID JOIN PUBLISHER_TABLE P ON B.PUBLISHER_ID = P.PUBLISHER_ID JOIN RATING_TABLE R ON B.ISBN = R.ISBN WHERE B.ISBN = '" + isbn + "'";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    txtBook.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["TITLE"]);
    txtGenre.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["BOOK_CATEGORY"]);
    txtISBN.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["ISBN"]);
    txtAuthor.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["AUTHOR_NAME"]);
    txtPublisher.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["PUBLICATION_HOUSE_NAME"]);
    txtyop.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["YEAR_OF_PUBLICATION"]);
    txtRating.Text =dr["AVERAGE"].ToString();
}

dr.Close();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Which textbox raises this exception?

Comment: I suspect some datarows are null.

Comment: Are you able to read the item into a decimal using the dr["..."] statement? Can you convert this decimal into a string using Decimal.ToString()? What is the real object type returned from the dr["..."] statement that has the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue for the problem. My Average which was being calculated, in some cases would end up being a non recurring value and would not end. Hence there used to be an error while casting.

I solved it using TO_CHAR function in the query.

```
 string sql = "SELECT distinct B.TITLE,B.BOOK_CATEGORY,B.ISBN,A.AUTHOR_NAME,P.PUBLICATION_HOUSE_NAME,B.YEAR_OF_PUBLICATION,(SELECT TO_CHAR((AVG(AVERAGE_RATING)),'99.99') FROM RATING_TABLE GROUP BY ISBN HAVING ISBN = '" + isbn + "') AS AVERAGE from BOOK_TABLE B JOIN AUTHOR_TABLE A ON B.AUTHOR_ID = A.AUTHOR_ID JOIN PUBLISHER_TABLE P ON B.PUBLISHER_ID = P.PUBLISHER_ID JOIN RATING_TABLE R ON B.ISBN = R.ISBN WHERE B.ISBN = '" + isbn + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope that `txtRating.Text =dr["AVERAGE"].ToString();` causing the error, this is not because of `decimal` to `string` casting as you specified. this may due to `dr["AVERAGE"]` be `null` and hence `null.ToString()` gives the error here: So you could use:

```
  txtRating.Text = dr["AVERAGE"] == null || dr["AVERAGE"] is DBNull ? "" : dr["AVERAGE"].ToString();
```

Comment: Should be something else because all those access to the DbReader cannot give Invalid Cast. Convert.ToString(DbNull.Value) or DbNull.Value.ToString() don't raise the specified exception

Comment: @Steve Exactly, there was no change with me making those changes. I run the query in the DB and I get the result. I get dr["AVERAGE"]=5.363636. So is that being a decimal an issue?

Comment: No, that should be no problem at all. The call ToString() should never fail if the value is DbNull.Value. An empty string is returned in that case. Also if you have a value in dr["AVERAGE"] calling ToString() could return a string formatted in your locale settings but not give an Invalid Cast exception, at least as far as I know. Are you sure the exception is raised on that line?

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with the code but,`dr["AVERAGE"]`, should not be null.
Else you will get `Object reference error`

Answer (score -3):

In PLSQL Casting

```
 SELECT CAST (null AS DOUBLE PRECISION) From dual; 
 SELECT CAST ('100.233' AS DOUBLE PRECISION) From dual; 
 Select AVG( CAST(AVERAGE_RATING AS DOUBLE PRECISION)) FROM RATING_TABLE;
```

OR in C#

```
try
{
 If(dr["AVERAGE"]!= null)
  {

  txtRating.Text = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["AVERAGE"].ToString()) ?  Convert.ToDecimal(dr["AVERAGE"].ToString()) : 0);
  }
}
 catch{}
```

Comment: what happend if `dr["AVERAGE"]= null` and also `Convert.ToDecimal()` throws format exception in case of canversion failure

Comment: `null.ToString()` will throws exception